# Dropdown doesn't align text

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

**Software:** Visual Web Developer 2008 Express Edition

**Book:** Programming ASP.NET 3.5 by O'REILLY

This is code from the book

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <p>
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server"
                AlternateText="Popfly Duck" ImageUrl="Images/ducky.jpg" />
            This is a sample paragraph which is being used to demonstrate
            the effects of various values of ImageAlign. As you will see,
            the effects are sometimes difficult to pin down, and vary 
            depending on the width of the browser window.
        </p>
        <hr />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Sample Button" />
        <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server"
            AlternateText="Popfly Duck" ImageUrl="Images/ducky.jpg" />
        <hr />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAlign" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="NotSet" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="AbsBottom" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="AbsBiddle" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Top" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Bottom" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="BaseLine" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="TextTop" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Left" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Right" />
        </asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    </form>
```

And here is the resulting webpage

[image]

But the book doesn't give the code behind page, i.e. aspx.cs, so I'm trying to determine the correct code so when user selects from drop-down, text will align accordingly. When I try

```
protected void ddlAlign_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    img1.ImageAlign = ddlAlign.Text;
}
```

I get red squiggly line under ddlAlign.Text. Help!

Comment: Did you check HTML source in web browser after select dropdown? If yes what you saw img tag?

Comment: @Glowie Please check the answer/answers and accept as right answer or put comment to share experience with others.

Comment: @QMaster --- When I return to office on Monday I'll check the answers and select right answer --- Merry Christmas!

Comment: @Glowie Thanks so much :) and Merry Christmas to you and your family.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ImageAlign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.imagealign%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an `enum`. You can't assign it with a `string`, so you have to parse it first. [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) can do that for you:

```
img1.ImageAlign = (ImageAlign)Enum.Parse(typeof(ImageAlign), ddlAlign.Text);
```

Comment: I will try this when I return to office on Monday --- Merry Christmas!